# Is it ok to block userInteraction on a view, when POSTing something to your server?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

Let's say you have a UINavigationController that collects data from the user as input. At the very end, the user can tap 'Save' to initiate a save to the backend via a web API.

Is it ok to do a `self.navigationController.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO` during the duration of the server call.

If not, what is the desired flow of things here? Just disabling the 'Save' UIBarButtonItem for the duration of the call? What is the user goes back in the navigation stack, forward again, and attempts to resubmit (lets say the users original network request is still sending due to limited connectivity).

Comment: This is really a user experience question and may be better asked on that site

Comment: yeah, you shoudl just do whatever you want to do, but I'd say the norm is to show a progress loader, it's there for UI effect but is basically useless, but I'd say that quite a few users are now becoming confused "not knowing whether the data saved" unless they see a loader and something or other that indicates a successful update.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.txt)

```
This allows user agents to represent other methods, such as POST, PUT
and DELETE, in a special way, so that the user is made aware of the
fact that a possibly unsafe action is being requested.  
...
The action performed by the POST method might not result in a
resource that can be identified by a URI. In this case, either 200
(OK) or 204 (No Content) is the appropriate response status,
depending on whether or not the response includes an entity that
describes the result.
```

TLDR: HTTP spec doesn't care what the user sees during POST request processing, it only cares about what is happening on the server (and maybe client authentication).

It might be a good idea to get requests from this view in a queue if network connectivity may be an issue. Then you could disable the UI feature responsible for sending requests while the queue isn't empty.

Answer (score 0):

Is the app unusable while the data is being saved?

If not, then there probably isn't a good reason to block interaction.

Keep track of your requests and their state, so that if it turns out that they fail you can retry or alert the user, and if a new request is created, you know the state of existing requests so you can decide how to best handle it.

If the app is unusable during the save, do something visual to dissuade the user from trying to interact with it, like a "Saving..." overlay or progress indicator. Disabling the Save button is also reasonable.